# SEO standards for CMS

Tags: web, seo

I am a web-programmer and my friend is a SEO-optimizer. He says: your handmaded CMS may be bad for SEO optimizing; I trust only big CMSes because they are created with thinking about SEO. But he doesn't know criteries for "to be a system that is good for SEO optimizing". Is there some list of them? Maybe some certificates for CMSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am partially agree with your friend as there is no harm creating handmade CMS if you follow basic SEO criteria listed below:

You should be able to:

- Add unique title meta into each page (in case of large number of pages, you should be able to add them dynamically by replacing product name, category etc)
- Add unique page name without query string (meaningful name)
- add content into respective pages
- It allows user to generate sitemap.xml, google analytics and other tracking script insertion and if require, you can also generate Google FEED (ecommerce website).

These are some basic and important requirements. If you think you can handle these, go with customized CMS.